# mysql sum multiple joins

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to write a `SELECT` query that joins multiple one-to-many tables. A table named **disbursements** has both a  `LEFT JOIN`  to a table named **contacts** (because a contact can have many disbursements) and a  `LEFT JOIN`  to a table named **pledges** (because a pledge (promise of payment) can have multiple disbursements (actual payments).

My question is how can I pull records that list contacts, their pledges, and the pledge balance (the sum of disbursements towards a pledge subtracted from the pledge)?

Here is what I got so far:

```
SELECT *, (p.pl_amount - SUM(disb_amount)) as balance FROM disbursements d
LEFT JOIN contacts c on c.c_no = d.c_no
LEFT JOIN  pledges p on d.pl_no = p.pl_no 
GROUP BY d.disb_no
HAVING balance > 500
ORDER BY c.c_last
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: What table is `disb_amount` in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you'll probably want to do is put the `contacts` table in the `FROM` clause instead of in a `LEFT JOIN` since you still want to retrieve contacts even when they don't have any disbursements/pledges.

Also since you seem to only want contacts that have a pledge balance > `500`, a `LEFT JOIN` isn't necessary unless you also want to retrieve contacts that DON'T have any pledges OR have a balance > `500`. I used a regular (inner) `JOIN` instead:

Try this:

```
SELECT    c.*,
          p.*,
          COALESCE(p.pl_amount - pd.disb_sum, 0) AS pledge_balance
FROM      contacts c
LEFT JOIN disbursements d ON c.c_no = d.c_no
LEFT JOIN pledges p ON d.pl_no = p.pl_no
LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT   pl_no, SUM(disb_amount) AS disb_sum
          FROM     disbursements
          GROUP BY pl_no
          ) pd ON p.pl_no = pd.pl_no
WHERE     p.pl_no IS NULL OR
          p.pl_amount - pd.disb_sum > 500
ORDER BY  c.c_last
```

Comment: Thanks!! This is almost what I need. I just have to figure out how to show a `pledge_balance` of `0` if there were no disbursements associated to a pledge.

Comment: @Ennui, see my updated solution for that. I believe it should work for what you're trying to do. It will only get the contacts who either have a pledge balance greater than 500, or who don't have any disbursements at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simplify this problem. If I understand correctly, your disbursements depend on your pledges (if there are no pledges, there are no disbursements). If this is true, then you can do something like this:

```
select 
    p.pl_no, p.pl_amount - sum(disb_amount) as balance
from 
    pledges as p
    left join disbursements as d on p.pl_no = d.pl_no
group by
    p.pl_no
having
    p.pl_amount - sum(disb_amount) > 500;
```

If you need the full info (contacts, pledges and disbursements), then you have to think this as a multi-step problem:

1. You need first the balance of the pledges
2. You need the contacts associated with the pledges
3. You need the full info of this records

So, the query above gives you the information you need for step 1. You can create a temporary table with this info:

```
Create temporary table temp_pledge_balance
select 
    p.pl_no, p.pl_amount - sum(disb_amount) as balance
from 
    pledges as p
    left join disbursements as d on p.pl_no = d.pl_no
group by
    p.pl_no;
```

I suggest you index this table, to speed up next steps:

```
Alter table temp_pledge_balance
    add index pl_no (pl_no);
```

Now, for step 2:

```
create temporary table temp_contacts
select c.*, p.pl_no
from
    temp_pledge_balance as pb
    inner join pledges as p on pb.pl_no=p.pl_no
    inner join contacts as c on p.c_no = c.c_no;
alter temp_contacts
    add index c_no(c_no);
```

Finally, for step 3:

```
select
   tc.*, pb.*, p.*, d.*
from
   temp_contacts as tc
   left join disbursements as d on tc.c_no = d.c_no
   left join pledges as p on d.pl_no = p.pl_no
   left join temp_pledge_balance as pb on p.pl_no = pb.p_no
where
   pb.balance > 500
```

A tricky solution, but it may help you.